# determining the type of element selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery selection, is there a way to determine what type of element it is (e.g. <a>,<span>,etc...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with a selector to see it it matches, like this:

```
var is_span = $(this).is("span");
```

Or if you have a DOM element:

```
var is_span = this.tagName == "SPAN";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#elementId").get(0).tagName
```